# Difference between addMapper functions

Tags: hadoop

What is the difference between

```
 ChainMapper.addMapper(conf, UpperCaserMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true, mapBConf);
```

and

```
ChainReducer.addMapper(conf, LastMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true, mapCConf);
```

When to use one.

Also i couldn't get the meaning of the 7th argument.
7th argument  -->  indicates if key/values should be passed by value to the next Mapper in the chain, if any.
I understand that the key/value has to be passed, if its set to true. What could be the use-case of setting the value to false. What does it means?

Comment: ok i got it that the 7th argument means pass by value or pass by reference. Still one question remains how does it do pass by reference from a mapper to a reducer. A reducer can run on a different machine than the mapper. Please explain anyone?

Answer (score 0):

There is no as such difference between ChainMapper.addMapper & ChainReducer.addMapper. Both are analogous to each other as they are adding a new Mapper to the Chain.

The very small difference that lies is:
If you wish to add a Mapper after a Map, you use ChainMapper.addMapper
If you wish to add a Mapper after a Reducer, you use ChainReducer.addMapper

So a job can run multiple mappers in a sequence for pre-processing and after running a reducer it can optionally run mappers to post process the data.
Hence using this mechanism you are writing pre processing and post processing steps as standard Mappers.

This is symbolized as Map+(multiple Mappers) - Reduce - Map*(optional).